# Firebase Facebook Login from Ionic (Cordova) app in iOS Emulator

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, facebook-authentication

I'm configuring my Ionic app to work with Facebook Authentication. Everything seems about right when I debug the app from my browser; however, when I deploy the app to the iOS emulator I get the following message in the safari console:

"This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console."

I suppose that makes sense. I went over to the Firebase console to add an additional domain name which my emulator was running on, but have no idea what the domain would be. I even tried logging "window.location.hostname" but it came up as completely blank when I run the app from the emulator (it's localhost when I run it from the browser). Any idea how to allow the emulator to utilize Firebase authentication? Thanks a bunch. Please let me know if I can provide additional details.

Answer (score 0):

You can import firebase 2.x and use the fb auth functionality with a instance of that library and firebase 3.x for the new features. Eventually, they should fix the bugs in 3.x, just be patience. This is a temporary solution, obviously.